# C# Passing values to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm passing a bool from one form to another, I have tried declaring 'Private bool useDBServer;' at the top of my class but this create a new variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Form1 below:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(dataGridView1, _useDBServer, _useOther);
```

Form2 below:

```
    public Form2(DataGridView dgv, bool useDBServer, bool useOther)
    {
       if(useDBServer) //<---- works here
       {
         //stuff
       }
    }


    private void readRegistry()
    {
       if(useDBServer) //<---- but not here
       {
         //stuff
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the variable in a different method, you'll have to have it as an instance variable, and copy the value in the constructor:

```
private readonly bool useDBServer;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv, bool useDBServer, bool useOther)
{
   this.useDBServer = useDBServer; // Copy parameter to instance variable
   if(useDBServer) 
   {
     //stuff
   }
}


private void readRegistry()
{
   if(useDBServer) // Use the instance variable
   {
     //stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form2(DataGridView dgv, bool _useDBServer, bool useOther)
    {
       useDBServer = _useDBServer;

       if(useDBServer) //<---- works here
       {
         //stuff
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
bool localUseDBServer;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv, bool useDBServer, bool useOther)
{
   localUseDBServer = useDBServer;

   if(localUseDBServer)
   {
     //stuff
   }
}

private void readRegistry()
{
   if(localUseDBServer)
   {
     //stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: is the down vote just because I posted the same thing as 2 other people at the same time? Or is there something wrong in what I posted?

Comment: @Matt: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't call an *instance* variable "localXXX"... it sounds like it's meant to be a local variable.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Didn't mean to imply you down voted. Someone did & I wondered why.  
Yes the name is bad but I wanted to imply the variable was local to the class without putting in the code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an argument to the constructor. How is that going to be used in a method within the class? You either need to 'save' the argument in an instance member variable. Or you need to forward the argument from the constructor to the method.